# Limiting nested Angular ng-repeat data structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to do an "infinite scroll" page with a nested data structure that has 4 levels, displayed via ng-repeats something like this:

```
Category 1
- Item
  - Sub Item 1
   - Activity A
   - Activity B
   - Activity C
  - Sub Item 2
   - Activity D
Category 2
```

I've been able to get an accurate index of a given item via the following function in my scope, but I'm not sure how to apply that to the filter on the various ng-repeats to cut off at say the 5th item (Activity B) in my list above.

```
$scope.itemIndex = function(item) {
    var count = 0;    
    if($scope.training[0] && $scope.training[0].Assigned.length > 0) {
      count++;
      if(item === $scope.training[0].Assigned) {  
        return count;
      }
      for (var n = 0; n < $scope.training[0].Assigned.length; n++) {
        count++;
        if(item === $scope.training[0].Assigned[n]) {  
          return count;
        }
        for (var r = 0; r < $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements.length; r++) {
          count++;
          if(item === $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements[r]) {  
            return count;
          }
          for(var a = 0; a < $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements[r].activities.length; a++) {
            count ++;
            if(item === $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements[r].activities[a]) {  
              return count;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've tried various combinations of a global counter in the scope and passing $index down through the children but have been unable to find a working solution. What would be the best way to limit the nested repeats with a single total count in a way where I can change the count dynamically?

Comment: AngularJS has built-in [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter for this: `ng-repeat="item in coll | limitTo: myLimitVar"`

Comment: I was using limitTo, but lets say the total items needed was 5, I can't put limitTo: 5 on the outer ng-repeat because I only need 1 item from that level, 1 item from the child repeat, 1 item from the grandchild repeat, and finally 2 items from the great grandchild. The problem then is if I get to 2 or more top parent level items on a page, the child/grandchild counts need to limit across multiple loops through the repeat.

Comment: Why don't you make a custom filter or directive to create a copy of the scope variable that has only the # items you need.  Seems easier than trying to use ng-repeat.  I could throw something together later to give you an idea if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think that could work. The only slight problem there is then I want to make the results filterable/searchable, but I'll just have to re-update the copy whenever a search or filter is performed so that should be fine. I'm a bit new to Angular, but I think I should be able to get that working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ng-if to limit the ng-repeat of each list to its acceptable scope.

Use ng-if on the index you said you got.

check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf for more insight into using the ng-if directive

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As your iterating over all your items you could keep track of a limit for each colection and then use those values in the `limitTo` for each `ng-repeat`. e.g.:

```
var MAX_ITEMS = 10;

$scope.updateLimits = function() {
    var count = 0;

    $scope.training[0].limit = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < $scope.training[0].Assigned.length; n++) {
        if (count < MAX_ITEMS) {
            $scope.training[0].limit++;
        }
        count++;

        $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].limit = 0;
        for (var r = 0; r < $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements.length; r++) {
            if (count < MAX_ITEMS) {
                $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].limit++;
            }
            count++;

            $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements[r].limit = 0;
            for (var a = 0; a < $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements[r].activities.length; a++) {
                if (count < MAX_ITEMS) {
                    $scope.training[0].Assigned[n].requirements[r].limit++;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I thought about something like this, but then lets say the total limit was 8 items and it ended on "activity D" from my list above that would be a seperate ng-repeat loop from the one that created activity A-C so even if I new I needed 4 activities total, I need to track that total across 2(or more) seperate ng-repeat loops so it seems using a limit on one individual loop won't work unless I can create a custom filter that somehow references a running count of remain items for each type.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using aarosil's suggestion above where I have a duplicate of the original data set that only contains the subset of data I want to display which removes the need to limit in the ng-repeats.